# Redirect to another page in React

Tags: reactjs

I know this same question has been asked multiple times but even after trying all of them it seems any of the solutions is working for me. My use case is simple, once a user has disconnected his wallet (because I'm developing an dapp), I want React to redirect to the home page. No buttons to click or whatever, once the event of disconnection is triggered, React must direct to home page. I show you what I'm trying to do:

```
const NavbarMenu = ({ typeNavbar }) => {

const navigate = useNavigate();    

useEffect(() => {

console.log("entra");
window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async function (accounts) {
  if (!accounts.length) {
    setWalletConnected(false);
    // goBack();
  } else {
    setWalletConnected(true);
  }
});
}, [])

const setFinalNavbar = () => {

if (typeNavbar == "homepage") {
  if (walletConnected) {
    return (<Nav.Link href="/myaccount">My Account</Nav.Link>);
  } else {
    return (<Button className={navbar_styles.connect_btn} variant="outline-success" onClick={connectWallet}>Connect Wallet</Button>);
  }
} else {
  if (walletConnected) {
    return (<Nav.Link href="/" className='text-success'>Back to home</Nav.Link>);
  } else {
    // return (navigate("/"));
    return (<Redirect to="/" />);
  }
}
}

return (
    <Navbar sticky="top" bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
          <img
            src="/favicon.ico"
            width="30"
            height="30"
            className="d-inline-block align-top"
            alt="React Bootstrap logo"
          />{' '}
          Four-Leaf
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Router>
              {typeNavbar == "personal"
                ? <>
                  <Nav.Link href="#home">Purchased numbers</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#bet-number">Previous numbers</Nav.Link>
                </>
                : <>
                  <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#bet-number">Bet</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#last-raffles">Last raffles</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#link">Instructions</Nav.Link>
                </>
              }
              {setFinalNavbar()}
            </Router>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  )

}
```

I've tried Redirect, BrowserRouter, useNavigate, and none of them is working for me.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
```

An this is the parent of NavbarMenu:

```
export default function MyAccount() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Navbar typeNavbar="personal" />
          <main className={home_styles.main}>
            <Reward />
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Using useNavigate hook throws this error:
*Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component.*

Comment: How did you try `useNavigate` exactly? That should work. Your `useEffect` looks incorrect. Are you sure you want to add a new listener on every render? I'd expect to see it here with an empty capture group.

Comment: Show your router logic

Comment: How would you do it @ggorlen? The thing is that you have to set up that listener at the load f the website. And useNavigate declaring it like: const navigate = useNavigate(); and then in those comments above use it like: navigate("/"). What do you think?

Comment: @Johan this is how I did it when I tried it with Router: 
const goBack = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </>
    )
  }. This goBack() function was called in the comment above.

Comment: Yes, an empty capture group would run when the component is created one time, but yours runs on every render. Yes, `navigate("/")` should work. Did you try it? If it didn't work, what error did you see exactly (and share a [mcve])? Any code edits should be in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @ggorlen I've edited my question but I can tell you that with navigate the error is: Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Comment: Are you using it in the context of a `<Router>` component?

Comment: No... I mean, I'm just calling it in the useEFfect and this is a Navbar component. So I guess it's a no. How would you wrap it like that?

Comment: I mean in this context because I've seen solutions using it but I'm new in React and I'm not sure how to adapt it to my own needs...@ggorlen

Comment: As Johan said, please show your routing. If this component isn't nested in a router, there's the problem.

Comment: @ggorlen I've edited the question but I don't know if that's what you mean by showing my routing. Sorry for my incompetence in this.

Comment: I think you need to walk through a basic RR tutorial. Your code doesn't make sense and you're not showing the parent component of `NavbarMenu`. There should be a `<BrowserRouter>` or other router wrapper on your component so React Router knows about it. Start with that, set up routes, then you can navigate.

Comment: I have posted more code in case that helps @ggorlen. As you can see, I'm using now Router in my NavbarMenu component, and you can see also its parent.

Comment: There's no router in the parent. Again, please walk through a basic RR tutorial.

Comment: I've followed the tutotrals about that but it keeps throwing errors, even if this time is different: ReferenceError: document is not defined. This is when <Router> is just above <Navbar> @ggorlen